# can not center input fields inside div

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

I am trying to center my form but even trying in all possible ways I can I am not able to achieve it.

```css
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  max-width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>::Members Area::</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/pure-min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>heading</h1>
        <h2 id="msg">Heading</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form class="pure-form" action="" method="post" id='loginform'>
          <div class="fields">
            <fieldset class="pure-group center" >
              <input type="text" required autofocus class="pure-input-1-2" value="" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
              <input type="password" required class="pure-input-1-2" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
              <input type="email" class="pure-input-1-2" value="" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="hidden" name="type" value="login" id="type">
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" name="loginbutton" id="button" value="login">Sign in</button>
          <div class="login-links"> 
            <a href="#" id="forgt">Forgot password ?</a>
            <a href="#" id="signin">Already have an account ?  <strong>Sign in</strong></a>
            <br />
            <a href="#" id="signup">Don't have an account ? <strong>Sign Up</strong></a>
          </div>   
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The text and buttons in the field are centered but the input fields are not centered I tried adding width to the content but it didn't helped if I add `<center>` it works But I want to do it with css please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `.pure-form .pure-group input` to `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block` in `pure-min.css`

or just override it in another stylesheet:

```
.pure-form .pure-group input{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/df1uakqq/)

Comment: Can you give some other solution as I am using CDN for pure-css and dont want to modify it after self-hosting it.

Comment: @raghuv can you try just overriding it like I did in the fiddle?